# Google Analytics property for my website is not receiving hits

Tags: google, google-analytics

I received this notification from google analytics:

> Property http://www.example.net is not receiving hits. Either your
> site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly.
>
> Google Tag Assistant Recordings can help you ensure that your site is
> tagged correctly.

[image]

So I used tag assistant to validate my Google app and the result was perfect.

[image]

But I still have that message and no statistics appear in my dashboard.

What is the wrong here? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagnostic messages in the GA interface can take a while to clear of their own accord.
If you are sure your site has the code correctly installed, and you are seeing data reporting as expected, you can simply click the Ignore option at the bottom of that diag. msg box.

Comment: He said no statistics show in his dashboard. I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your site's metrics analyzer may be disabling analysis for you as the site owner, which essentially disconnects GA for you, specifically, as the site owner. This will not affect other traffic. You can also try accessing GA from another browser that does not have administrative access to the site to see if the notice goes away.

Comment: "Your site's metrics analyzer may be disabling analysis for you as the site owner, which essentially disconnects GA for you, specifically, as the site owner." do you have a link to documentation that states this?

Comment: The result of testing and experimentation.